# DQL return files in a Cabinet

Tags: dql, documentum

Using DQL I want to return all the documents under the Cabinet *test*. How would I go about writing a query to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select r_object_id, object_name from dm_document(all) where folder('/NameOfCabinet', descend);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with the all predicate, as this will return all versions, not just current versions.

Comment: You say that like it's a bad thing, shsteimer :)

Answer (score 1):

select * from dm_document where folder('/NameOfCabinet', descend); It will only return the current version of all the documents but not the all the version.

To see all the versions.

select * from dm_document(all) where folder('/NameOfCabinet', descend);